SQL Server Database Connection Timing Out. VPN Connection Good, SSH Connection Bad
Running a Rails 7.2 application connecting to an ancient remote SQL server for work.
Using Net::SSH::Gateway and .open() for the SSH and port forwarding in the database.yml file

I can VPN my dev computer into the network and connect to the database using the remote IP (192.168.x.x) and port.
The computer in the remote computer's network that is also hosting a Rails Server, can connect to the database.
With host set to 127.0.0.1 and port set to .open(), I can connect to the Postgresql database hosted on the remote server.
keeping the same settings in #1, changing host to 127.0.0.1 and the port to .open(), the SQL server connection timesout.

What could I be doing wrong? I'm out of ideas.

Can you post the actual database.yml? Additionally I am a bit confused why you are connecting to the database via SSH. Generally connecting to the database would be accomplished using a database adapter, older versions may use ODBC as well.

Are you sure it's connecting to the specified port when using the VPN? e.g.: If you're using an instance name in your connection details, such as 192.168.x.x\SQLEXPRESS, then it will be communicating with the SQL Browser service on the target machine to resolve the instance name SQLEXPRESS to the port that it's listening on and then connecting to that port. This would work over a VPN, but not over an SSH tunnel.

I'm using an SSH connection into a remote computer which has access to the SQL server. This SQL server is only accessible in the private network,

I'm using OpenVPN on my development computer to access the remote server and gain access to that private network. All IP's on the private network, including the SQL Database is accessible. I can connect just fine. When I use SSH in rails, it doesn't.
